# pgadmin4 cannot be started, how to fix it?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

> ```
> [The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:  Fatal Erroe][1]
>
>
>   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZk57.png
>
> pgAdmin Runtime Environment
> --------------------------------------------------------
> Python Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe"
> Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\haha\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
> pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py"
> Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
> pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin
> ```
>
> 4\web\pgAdmin4.py"
> Environment:
> - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
> - APPDATA: C:\Users\haha\AppData\Roaming
> - CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME: \.\pipe\crashpad_2864_HVAALLTNGAOWVHCO
> - CHROME_RESTART: NW.js|哎呀！NW.js 崩溃了。要立即重新启动吗？|LEFT_TO_RIGHT
> - CLASSPATH: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\jre\lib\ext
> - CommonProgramFiles: C:\Program Files\Common Files
> - CommonProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
> - CommonProgramW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
> - COMPUTERNAME: HAHA-PC
> - ComSpec: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
> - FP_NO_HOST_CHECK: NO
> - HOMEDRIVE: C:
> - HOMEPATH: \Users\haha
> - JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot
> - LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\haha\AppData\Local
> - LOGONSERVER: \HAHA-PC
> - NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 1
> - OS: Windows_NT
> - Path: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
> - PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
> - PGADMIN_INT_KEY: bfe01206-8bc4-4bd4-9293-472dd90ae0ab
> - PGADMIN_INT_PORT: 49163
> - PGADMIN_SERVER_MODE: OFF
> - PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
> - PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
> - PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
> - PROCESSOR_REVISION: 9e0a
> - ProgramData: C:\ProgramData
> - ProgramFiles: C:\Program Files
> - ProgramFiles(x86): C:\Program Files (x86)
> - ProgramW6432: C:\Program Files
> - PSModulePath: C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
> - PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
> - SESSIONNAME: Console
> - SystemDrive: C:
> - SystemRoot: C:\Windows
> - TEMP: C:\Users\haha\AppData\Local\Temp
> - TMP: C:\Users\haha\AppData\Local\Temp
> - USERDOMAIN: haha-PC
> - USERNAME: haha
> - USERPROFILE: C:\Users\haha
> - windir: C:\Windows
> - windows_tracing_flags: 3
> - windows_tracing_logfile: C:\BVTBin\Tests\installpackage\csilogfile.log
> --------------------------------------------------------
>
> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 39, in <module>
>     import config
>   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py", line 25, in <module>
>     from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
>   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
>     from flask import Flask, abort, request, current_app, session, url_for
>   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
>     from jinja2 import escape
>   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
>     from .environment import Environment
>   File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 46, in
> ```
>
> from .lexer import get_lexer
>       File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\jinja2\lexer.py", line 46, in 
>         compile("f\xf6\xf6", "", "eval")
>     ImportError: DLL load failed while importing unicodedata: ��������

Comment: Same error here!